# How many probability vectors do I need to convexly generate any probability vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, convex-geometry, simplex

Fix a positive integer $n$, and let $B = \{p_1, \dots, p_{k}\}$ be a set of $k$ mutually linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$, where each $p_i \in B$ is also a probability vector in the probability simplex $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$. I am interested in the minimum value of $k$ such that I can express the $2^n$ vectors $(1,0,\dots, 0), (0,1,0,\dots, 0), \dots, (0,\dots, 0,1)$ in $\Delta$ as a convex sum of vectors in $B$. Evidently, if $k = 2^n$, then $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$ and so I can do it. But $B$ being a basis merely entails that each $p \in \Delta$ is a linear combination (not necessarily a *convex* combination) of vectors in $B$. Any help would be appreciated, particularly references to the relevant ideas.

**Edit**

To clarify the quantifiers (and to remove the linear independence condition), I am interested in the least $k$ such that for *any* collection $B$ of $k$ probability vectors in $\Delta$, I can write any $p \in \Delta$ as a convex sum of elements in $B$. Certainly there must be at least $2^n$ linearly independent vectors in $B$, so $k \geq 2^n$, but presumably there must also be additional vectors in $B$ to satisfy the convexity constraint.

Comment: The quantifiers are a little ambiguous: you're looking for the least $k$ such that there exists $B$... ?

Comment: The convex hull of $B$ contains $(1,0, \dots, 0)$ etc iff it contains all of $\Delta$.  So $k < 2^n$ can't work, as the convex hull is contained in the linear span whose dimension is too low.  And trivially $k = 2^n$ does work since you can simply let $B$ be all the vectors you want.  Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: You certainly need at least $2^n$ vectors, since if $e_i$ are all convex combinations of the $p_i$, then the $p_i$ are spanning for $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$. You can have at most $2^n$ independent vectors in that space, so by the conditions you've given, $k = 2^n$ is the only value that could possibly work.

Comment: @NateEldredge I clarified the quantification.

Comment: @NicholasPriebe Good point. Thinking about it a bit more you're right that I'm putting myself into a corner. I think the question I have actually doesn't concern the linear independence. I'll edit again.

Comment: The clarified version seems impossible.  It is certainly possible to find a set of $k = 2^n$ linearly independent vectors in $\Delta$ whose convex hull does not contain all of $\Delta$.  For instance with $n=1$ consider $B = \{(1/2,1/2), (1/4, 3/4)\}$.  And if $k > 2^n$ then they won't be linearly independent.

Comment: Yes, sorry @NateEldredge, I clarified again.

Comment: But it's impossible again, because for any $k$ you can easily find $k$ vectors which don't generate $\Delta$.  In fact, $B$ will generate $\Delta$ if and only if it actually contains the specific vectors $(1,0,\dots,0), (0,1,0,\dots,0), \dots$ which are the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of $\Delta$.

Comment: In other words, you can't write $(1,0,\dots,0)$ as a finite convex combination of any other elements of $\Delta$.

Comment: Ahh yes that's so trivial! Thanks! Happy to accept if you put this into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't write $(1,0,\dots,0)$ as a convex combination of other probability vectors, no matter how many you have: they are the [extreme points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_point) of $\Delta$.  For suppose we have $v_i = (v_{i,1}, \dots, v_{i, 2^n})$ for $i=1,\dots,m$,  If $v_i \ne (1,0,\dots,0)$ then $v_{i,1} < 1$.  So the first element of a convex combination is at most $\max_i v_{i,1} < 1$.

As such, a set $B$ generates $\Delta$ if and only if it contains $(1,0,\dots,0), (0,1,0,\dots,0)$, etc.